# Is this generalization of prime gaps also bounded?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that it has been proven that prime gaps are bounded. Meaning, no matter how far you go along the number line, you will keep finding consecutive primes less than a fixed distance, which I believe was proven to be at most 70 million or so. However, I want to generalize this, and ask whether the gap between $p_n$ and $p_{n+2}$, where $p_n$ is the nth prime number, is also bounded. In fact, I want to know, is it true that for any positive integer $k$, the gap between $p_n$ and $p_{n+k}$ is also bounded? Or, is there a smallest positive integer $k$ where the gap is no longer bounded?

Comment: This is an eccentric use of the term "bounded" which, after all, has a universally accepted meaning.  Why not use another term?

Comment: @lulu "Has finite liminf" perhaps? It doesn't flow so nicely, though, and I don't know that there is a more elegant phrasing that sounds better.

Comment: @Arthur  I agree, but that's not a reason to use a word with a universally accepted meaning to mean something entirely different.  Better to call such sequences "good" or whatever.

Comment: I think you will find that if you explore the Polymath project on prime gaps the figure of $70$ million has been considerably reduced ($246$? and a contingent $6$) and the gaps for two, three four and more primes have been explored, and bounded explicitly for low values - https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an integer $H_k < cke^{4k}$ (for some constant $c$) such that there are infinitely many $x \in \mathbb{N}$ for which there at least $k$ primes in the interval $[x, x + H_k]$. For a paper on this, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897).